# Cube Sculpting Tool

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

Is there any way to create a sculpting tool that will deform an object to the extent that the area sculpted will become a cube? So far I've only succeeded in create a tool that uses the layering sculpting tool to create slightly raised squares. If I increase the height that the tool sculpts, the squares deform greatly and I do not think I'm on the right track to creating the tool that I need. Am I missing something obvious? Any suggestions?

Comment: I thought the voxel remesher had an option to spit out a 'cubified' result. I can check when I get time.

Answer (score 0):

The *Remesh Modifier* has a *Blocks* option that will make the underlying mesh display in a cube-volumetric style.

[image]

Edit mode view, it's just the default sculpt mode sphere that I made a few brush strokes to.

[image]